# Opencart Multiple Featured Module on Home Page

Tags: php, opencart

I have added two featured module from admin and want to show each module on different city.

Example, two Modules as below:

- Featured Module Mumbai
- Featured Module Delhi

When City is Mumbai only Featured Module Mumbai should display on home page and same as for Delhi.

Comment: What is opencart version ? show you url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stored city in session and match with featured name. Here is code...

```
if(isset($this->session->data['city_name'])) 
{ 
    $city = $this->session->data['city_name']; 
}
else
{
    $city = ''; 
}

if(isset($city) && $city == 'Mumbai' && $setting['name'] == 'Featured Venue For Mumbai City')
{
    ...
}
```